# Updating a python dictionary with regex groups

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, regex-group

I am iterating through a log file and need to update the values of a dictionary with a regex match that is within a group. when I try using error_msg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqzLI.png) "I get IndexError: list index out of range".

Here are sample lines from the syslog file I am matching to =

May 27 11:45:40 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: Created ticket [#1234] (username)

May 24 11:44:12 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Timeout while retrieving information [#34504] (username)

May 24 11:44:12 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Failed to Connect to Database [#44514] (username)

There is another dictionary, "per_user", that is working correctly and incrementing the 'INFO' and 'ERROR' counts per user.

```
error = {}
per_user = {}
with open('syslog.log', 'r') as file: #opening the syslog file
    for line in file.readlines():
        pattern1 = r"ticky: INFO: ([\w ]*) " #info message
        pattern2 = r"ticky: ERROR: ([\w ]*) " #error message
        pattern3 = r"(\([\w]*\))$" #username
        info_msg = re.findall(pattern1, line)
        error_msg = re.findall(pattern2, line)
        user = re.findall(pattern3, line)
        for x in user:
            x = x.strip('()')
            if x not in per_user:
                per_user[x] = {'INFO':0,'ERROR':0}
            if info_msg is not None:
                per_user[x]['INFO'] += 1
            if error_msg is not None:
                per_user[x]['ERROR'] += 1  
        if error_msg is not None:
            for errors in error_msg:
                if errors not in error:
                    error[errors] = 0
                error[errors] += 1

    file.close()
```

Why doesn't my error dictionary add keys for error_msg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqzLI.png) and increment the count of each message?

These are example tables my dictionaries will populate for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If `error_msg[1]` gives an `IndexError` then `error_msg = re.findall(pattern2, line)` isn't returning at least 2 matches

Comment: It's unlikely to be related to the issue, but you don't need to explicitly close the file in there, nor do you need to use `.readlines()`.

Comment: Just after `if error_msg is not None:` add `print(error_msg)` - is it what you expected? Maybe also add that just after the `re.findall(pattern2, line)` line. It should help you track it down.

Comment: _when I try using error_msg1 "I get IndexError: list index out of range"._ Please share the entire error message. Is what you shared already a [mcve]? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: `re.findall()` returns an empty list if there are no matches - `if error_msg is not None:` should be `if error_msg:`

Comment: I ran your code with the sample lines from the log and could not reproduce your problem ... `error` got updated - `{'Failed to Connect to Database': 1, 'Timeout while retrieving information': 1}`

Comment: @wwii after printing(error_msg) I get a bunch of [] empty brackets in new lines. I get this moving print and the if not none line anywhere. When I use sample code lines it works as well - is there a reason why it wouldn't be working on the actual .log file being parsed?

Comment: @wwii how would you change the if error_msg is not None line? I realized my count for per_user dictionary is just adding the info and error no matter what because as empty lists, info_msg and error_msg always != None. I tried if (len(error_msg) > 1 == True but nothing registered.

Answer (score 0):

Once check whether there is ":" after ERROR and INFO in the log file

Hope this helps :)

```
            if x not in per_user:
                per_user[x] = {'INFO':0,'ERROR':0}
            if info_msg != []:
                per_user[x]['INFO'] += 1
            if error_msg != []:
                per_user[x]['ERROR'] += 1  
        if error_msg != []:
            for errors in error_msg:
                if errors not in error:
                    error[errors] = 0
                error[errors] += 1
```